# How do you programatically post to a remote web site with authentication using WebClient?

Tags: .net, html

I have the following site http://localhost/abc.htm which requires authorization

```
<form method="POST" action="/change">
<input type="hidden" name="node" value="12 4A 72 1" /><table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="On" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Off" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I'm trying to programatically post to this form as if I pressed the submit button "on".  So 
far I've been able to authenticate and download the page using the WebClient class.

```
    Dim myCache As New CredentialCache()
    Dim req As New WebClient()
    Dim results As String
    myCache.Add(New Uri(URL), "Basic", New NetworkCredential(UserName, Password))
    req.Credentials = myCache
    results = UTF8.GetString(req.DownloadData(URL))
```

Now I'm trying to simulate pressing the button using UploadValues

```
    Dim mvc As New NameValueCollection
    mvc.Add("node", "12 4A 72 1")
    mvc.Add("submit", "On")
    req.UploadValues(URL, mvc)
```

However on the last line, I'm getting "The request was aborted: The request was canceled".

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?  Am I even using the correct set of classes for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

This article might help: [WebClient UploadFile errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634470/webclient-uploadfile-errors)

If you're getting TimeOuts then: http://geekswithblogs.net/SoftwareDoneRight/archive/2010/09/14/supporting-request-timeout-with-a-webclient.aspx